# Unity3D WebGL export does not show Hangul (Korea language)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, language-packs

So, my Unity3D project has some Korean text. When I play it, everything works perfectly. However, when I build it into WebGL and open it in browser all the Korean characters disappear. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I expected, the solution to the above problem is to import your own font. Here's the link for more details: [from Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Font.html)